# Custom CSS to achieve same result as list-style-type: decimal;

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to to order items in a list by giving them an index. I know that I can achieve the same result by using an `<ol>` or `list-style-type: decimal` but the problem is that there are some `<li>` in my code that have `display: none;`. Those `<li>` are basically ignored and the index continues as if they never were there.

So to retain the index order even on elements with `display: none;`, I'm giving them an index myself.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to make my own indexes ident the same way as `list-style-type: decimal` would do.

My indexes:

[image: http://image.prntscr.com/image/8bf2767b660b41cf80d2963dea2488fc.pn]

`list-style-type: decimal`:

[image]

As you can see the `list-style-type: decimal` are nicely aligned, how can I achieve the same result for custom indexes?

My code so far:

```
{{#each users}}
    <li class="{{status this.online}}">
        <span id="counter">{{counter @index}}.</span>
        <a class="{{status this.online}}" href="/players/{{this.user}}">
            {{this.user}}
        </a>, the level {{level}} {{char_class}}. Next level in {{duration secs}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could like this, where you use a pseudo, give it a width and right align the text.

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: test;
  list-style: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: test;
  content: counter(test) '.';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

---

Update based a comment

Add a class like this for your span

```
ul li span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: The problem is https://jsfiddle.net/kxwjbh84/ that when i use `display: none;` for one of the elements. The index continues for example in the jsfiddle `Some text3` gets the index no `2`, instead of `3`. That's why I have made my own index in the code `<span id="counter">{{counter @index}}.</span>` I just would like that to have same identation as `list-style-type: decimal` has.

Comment: @Drago Updated my answer with a CSS rule that does the same to your `span` as it does to my initial sample